# Fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'FlashDXDebug_Win32.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, directx, fatal-error

I have downloaded [this](https://github.com/wy182000/flash-to-directx) and run the gui.sln in the samples folder and have seen that I could not include a 3d....(don`t know the name anymore, sorry for this) library and had to download the DirectX SDK (June 2010). After the downloading and installation part I have built it again and get the error message as you can see in the title. What can I do to fix the problem???

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This path should work
https://github.com/wy182000/flash-to-directx

Comment: "this" gives me a 404 error. Have you told the project where the library is (in the linker settings)?

Comment: Hold on a second, I did a mistake with the path

Comment: 'FlashDXDebug_Win32.lib' appears to be one of the libraries in the solution - does that build? Do you have any other errors?

Comment: No other errors at the moment, and how can I check if the library was build